# Will adding a second SPF record mess up my DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, reverse-dns

Will adding a second SPF record mess up my DNS, or will it be like adding an extra nameserver?

(i.e. it only helps, not hurts)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [RFC 4408](http://www.openspf.org/svn/project/specs/rfc4408.txt):

```
3.1.2.  Multiple DNS Records

   A domain name MUST NOT have multiple records that would cause an
   authorization check to select more than one record.  See Section 4.5
   for the selection rules.
```

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve by adding a second record, but if it is something like adding extra hosts/networks as valid/invalid senders, you can probably do everything you want to with just the one record - just add whatever you wanted to the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

An SPF record can include multiple domains (multiple mechanisms is the correct term), so more than one spf record will never be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [on-line SPF generator](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html?mydomain=example.com&submit=Go%21) to get the appropiate TXT for SPF.

Comment: Not anymore as it seems

Comment: http://www.spfwizard.net/ here is another one.